# Как заставить Timer перейти к следующем тику?

Tags: java, swing, таймер

Условно, таймер работает с задержкой 5 секунд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как описать событие, происходящее в середине ожидания, чтобы ожидание заканчивалось и сразу происходил следующий тик, а ожидание начиналось заново (5 секунд):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    {код тика}
}

public void btnClicked(){
    {код события, после которого должен моментально начаться actionPerformed}
}
```

Пробовал вызывать `actionPerformed(null)`, тик отрабатывается моментально, но таймер выдает еще один свой "правильный" очередной тик через 5 сек от предыдущего. Получается 3 тика за 5 секунд.

Answer (score 1):

Таймер на каждую секунду. В таймере счетчик. При нажатии счетчик сбрасывается. Если счетчик больше 5 - вызываем actionPerformed() и сбрасываем опять таймер.

Счетчики:

```
int count = 0;
int maxCount = 5;
```

Таймер:

```
Timer timer = new Timer()
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;

        if(count > maxCount) {
            actionPerformed();
        } 
    }
});
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

И событие тика:

```
actionPerformed() {
    count = 0;
}
```

---

Либо ресетим таймер при каждом тике:

Таймер:

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        actionPerformed(null);
    }
});
```

Событие тика:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    if(timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 5000);
}
```

---

Второй способ правильней, т.к. в первом будет не ровно 5 секунд, а промежуток от 4 до 5.